# Does google chorme version 75 support .arrayBuffer()?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jszip

Help me, Does google chorme version 75 support .arrayBuffer()?. In Google Chrome version 75, the function .arrayBuffer is reported as not being a function

I have tested it on higher versions, and .arrayBuffer works normally.
And here is the piece of code that I use involving .arrayBuffer():
`Array.from(file.files).forEach((f, i) => { zip.file(f.webkitRelativePath, f.arrayBuffer()) })`

Comment: It was [supported since version 42](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_response_arraybuffer).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is not supported in version 75. Instead you can try this I think it will work

```
Array.from(file.files).forEach((f, i) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    // e.target.result contains the file contents as an ArrayBuffer
    zip.file(f.webkitRelativePath, e.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).